# Exchanging rows and columns in

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a way to somehow bring the information of different rows in to different/one column.
This is the problem:
Assume that I have 10 different sellers and 1000 buyers.
Currently this is how data structured (picture)
[image]
So for each sale, I have a row with the id of the seller and a buyer who bought something from him. What I want to have is to have 1 row for each seller and then in one/different columns I want to see the id of the buyer.

I am using snowflake and read about different ways but none of them really works.
I also have a timestamp column in this table and the only thing that I could think up until now is to

```
SELECT seller,
       rank()over(partition by seller order by purchase_date desc)
```

and after that I can use aggregation functions - this is not really a wise solution and not really practical when I have 10 -20 or more buyers.
What is the best approach for solving these types of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using listagg function as per the snowflake documentation

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html

```
--This will create a concatenated list of buyers seperated by a comma
select seller
       ,listagg(buyer,',') within group(order by buyer)
  from table
group by seller
```